# recursive call resulting into overflow

Tags: clojure

I am trying to solve the project euler 2nd question. Why is the below code resulting into stack overflow ? I am using recur so it should not be storing all the recursive calls on the stack.

```
(defn sum
  [[a b]]
  [b (+ a b)])

(defn fib-r
  ([n] (fib-r n 0 [0 1]))
  ([n s [a b]]
     (if (= n 0)
       s
       (let [[c d] (sum [a b])
             e (if (even? c) c 0)
             f (+ s e)]
         (recur (dec n) f [c d])))))

(fib-r 4000000)
```

Comment: You are recursing 4000000 times (i.e. computing the 4 million-th Fibonacci number), the question only asks for Fibonacci numbers *under* 4000000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your getting an integer overflow (rather than a stack overflow)
If you use BigInts (BigInt literals end with N) then Clojure will
happily compute the correct result:

```
(defn fib-r                                                                                          
  ([n] (fib-r n 0N [0N 1N]))                                                                     
  ([n s [a b]]                                                                                     
     (if (= n 0N)                                                                            
       s                                                                            
       (let [[c d] (sum [a b])                                               
             e (if (even? c) c 0N)                               
             f (+ s e)]                             
         (recur (dec n) f [c d])))))
#'autotestbed.core/fib-r                                                                                               
autotestbed.core> (fib-r 40000)
1158997879999727672946417013062336891791160667328280503727448.... big number
```

Comment: I just tried with 4 million, and the repl just hang. Is it because the computation is lo large ?

Comment: I timed it and it took 7.28 min on my desktop

Answer (score 1):

This was a big change made in Clojure 1.3 (see http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Enhanced+Primitive+Support for details) auto-promotion of primitive types does not happen automatically.

You don't have to use BigInts everywhere as Arthur Ulfeldt suggests, you can instead use auto-promoting plus operation `+'`:

```
(defn sum [[a b]] [b (+' a b)])
```

This will do.

In regards to the 4 million case - yes this computation is large. You can modify your `fib-r` function like this:

```
(defn fib-r
  ([n] (fib-r n 0 [0 1]))
  ([n s [a b]]
     (if (and (< 0 n) (zero? (mod n 100000)))
       (println n))
     (if (= n 0) s
       (let [[c d] (sum [a b])
             e (if (even? c) c 0)
             f (+ s e)]
         (recur (dec n) f [c d])))))
```

to see how fast this is going.